# An example concerning some fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, field-theory, finite-fields

I was trying to understand the following example

[image]

This is also why I've made some questions today on locally finite fields.

I've almost understand everything (thanks also to some of you) but I still have two problem. First when he say that "It follows easily that either $H$ is finite or $H=G$", it is really easy? There is maybe some result I had to use to derive this?

The second point I cannot understand is when he say that $G$ is of infinite rank. Essentially we have to find in $G$ subgroups that can be generated by $n$ but not from $m$ ($<n$) elements (choosing $n$ as large as we want).

**Definition**
A group $G$ is said to be of finite rank $r$ if all finitely generated subgroups can be generated by $r$ elements and $r$ is the least positive integer satisfying this condition.

The reference cited in [17, Theorem 6.25] is from the classic book of Suzuki "Group Theory I".

The class $(\mathfrak{A}^2)^*$ is the class of groups with all infinite proper subgroups metabelian (i.e. the commutator subgroups of these subgroups are abelian).

Answer (score 1):

#### For the first point:

It is probably easy. The gist is that those subfields $K_i$ either form an infinite (properly) ascending union of fields, so $K_\infty = F$ and $H=G$, or they are bounded above and $K_\infty$ is a finite field, so $H$ is finite.

XXX: I'm working out the details to make sure I understand this clearly. I'm confident that what I've said leads to a proof, but I'd like to make sure the details are as nice as I think they are (If $H_n$ is standard, and $i \leq n$, I'd like to claim $H_i$ is standard. From this, I think the proof is very clean, but I'm not sure I really understand what the other conjugates of $\operatorname{SL}(2,K)$ in $\operatorname{SL}(2,F)$ look like.)

#### For the second point:

$\operatorname{PSL}(2,F)$ has a subgroup isomorphic to the additive group of $F$ (called a maximal unipotent subgroup; in this case, also called a Sylow $p$-subgroup where $p$ is the characteristic of $F$). Hence if $|F_i|=p^{n_i}$, then $G$ has rank at least $n_i$.

As you mentioned, the image of the subgroup $\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} : x \in K \right\} \leq \operatorname{SL}(2,K) \leq \operatorname{SL}(2,F)$ in $\operatorname{PSL}(2,K) \leq \operatorname{PSL}(2,F)$is isomorphic to the additive group of $K$, which has rank equal to its dimension over its prime field (so if $|K|=p^n$, then this subgroup has rank $n$). This mostly follows a direct calculation and the definition of vector space basis.

Note that the inclusions of $\operatorname{SL}(2,K) \leq \operatorname{SL}(2,F)$ is true even at the level of set theory, but is called “standard” in Suzuki's book. The inclusion of $\operatorname{PSL}(2,K) \leq \operatorname{PSL}(2,F)$ is the image of the standard inclusion under two different projection maps (so not true at the level of sets), but the kernels are compatible in the correct way to make the image also a monomorphism.

Comment: About the second point I've understood why there is a subgroup isomorphic to the additive group of $F$ (we need just to take this "kind" of matrices
\begin{array}{cc}
   \pm 1 & f \\
   0 & \pm 1 \\
  \end{array} , is it correct?). The additive group of $F_i$ is an abelian elementary $p$-group and consequently the minimal number of generators increase every time we increase $i$. Right?

Comment: About the first point I've some problem: $H\cap G_i$ are simply isomorphic to $PSL(2,\, K_i)$, for instance so I can not see how we can do the kind of reasoning you do. Can you provide me more details, please?

Comment: For the second: exactly.   For the first: Oh, the theorem is not that they are isomorphic, they are (conjugate? maybe just actually exactly equal) to those subgroups. I'll look for a reference. At any rate, the embeddings are "natural".

Comment: Suzuki's 6.18 on page 405 and 6.20 on page 408 are the "natural" claims. Let me know if you want me to write up how to union them.

Comment: I really appreciate you for your patience with me. Thank you.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/1ALNI.png
This is the theorem I have. When you say that the embeddings are natural do you actually mean that $PSL(2,K_i)$ is the real subgroup of $G$ generated by allowing matrices on $K_i$? If so, then how we are supposed to deal with $PGL$? Or maybe with the point $(c)$ of the theorem 6.25 which also allows $A_5$ or $S_4$, for instance? (I find that they are isomorphic to some PGL or PSL but also in this case the embeddings are natural?).

Comment: If you could write the "union" (with some notes about my doubts) I'll be glad to read them. Thanks again.

Comment: I was just thinking how to use 6.20 and 6.18: perhaps one has to use the fact that if I have a finite $p$-subgroup I can always find a subgroup that contains it and is a $p$-sylow, and so I can use (by 6.20) the same element to conjugate "almost all" the ascending subgroups $H\cap G_i$ and then using your first argument. But I've just used 6.20, I think... 

I know my reasoning is a confusing one, so I will wait your surely clearer explanation.

Comment: It's been a busy day, so I haven't had much time to work it out. I wrote up the second point clearly, and indicated the conjecture that (combined with what you said) forms a very nice proof. However, I haven't had a chance to make sure the claim is true (I don't see how it could be completely false, but maybe it needs to be stated more carefully). Anyways, I'll work out the details.

Comment: Do not worry. Take your time. But (there is always a but) why the inclusion $PSL(2,\, K)\leq PSL(2,\, F)$ is not true in set theory? Don't we factor out always by the same subgroup (of $PSL(2,\, K)$) in both side of the inequality? Aren't the cosets the same? There is some tricky argument here, I smell it.